# Add ProgressBar Webview in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, progress

I want to add a progress bar in my `class` but i only found for `Extend Activity` and i use a drawer so `Fragment`

This is my code how to add this `progressbar`

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}

    WebView myWebView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        myWebView = (WebView) root.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.11/MAMP/isn/profil.php");



        return root;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed to add progressBar in my layout and I show/hide it from the Fragment itself

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentT4, container, false);
    progressBarT4 = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBarT4);

    webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webViewT4);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            progressBarT4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBarT4.setProgress(progress);
            if (progress == 100) {
                progressBarT4.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded
            }
        }
    });

    progressBarT4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.11/MAMP/isn/profil.php");
}
```

You will need to add few variables in the class declaration

```
public class FragmentT4 extends Fragment {
    private View rootView = null;
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBarT4 = null;
   ...
```

Also watch out for your layout and make sure that you have the progressBar on top of your webView

Comment: where is ?? CustomWebChromeClient() can not find

Comment: Just use WebChromeClient() - sorry I had openFileChoosed customized and extended it as  protected class CustomWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient. I updated the anwer.